# Best way to route differently based on a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a testimonial model that belongs to a user. User can have only one testimonial.

If the user accesses `/testimonial`, I want it to have different behaviors depending if user has testimonial and if user has already attended an event.

I've thought about the following function. I would check if the user has attended any event and not written a testimonial, the user would be directed to create. Else, he/she would be directed to see the already written testimonial or the message that have not yet attended any event.

Is this correct? How would routing work in this case?

```ruby
def get_testimonial
        testimonial = Testimonial.find(testimonial_member_id)
        invitations = current_user.workshop_invitations.accepted_or_attended.order_by_latest.includes(workshop: :chapter)

        if invitations.any? and testimonial.blank?
            # if member doesn't have testimonial, but has attended event, go to create
            render 'create'
        elsif invitations.any?
            # if member already wrote testimonial, show
            render 'show'
        else
            # has not attended event yet, so can't write testimonials
            @message = false 
        end
   end
```

Comment: You would want to render `'new'`, not `'create`' ... "create" is a POST action which creates the record ... "new" is the form to create a new record

Comment: I see, but would that be fine? for a route to first call get_testimonial and then render to new or show?

Comment: Are you having any issues with the way it is implemented currently? Using the controller action to render different views based on your application logic seems reasonable

Comment: Not anymore, thanks! I am now facing a problem when rendering `'new'`

Comment: @algora you probably have to throw in a `@invitation = Invitation.new` or something like that ... look at what data the template expects

Comment: undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

I'm having this error, when calling new.html.haml. Still not sure why :/